# POST http://localhost/site1/SGE_Proyecto/db/crud.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-404, crud

im creating a CRUD for a dashboard, and i have this error

> POST http://localhost/site1/SGE_Proyecto/db/crud.php 404 (Not Found) jquery-3.6.4.mion.js:2"

i think the problem is in this part of the code but i dont understan why

```
CRUD.PHP
-----------
<?php
include_once '../db/db.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();
// Recepción de los datos enviados mediante POST desde el JS   

$nombre = (isset($_POST['nombre'])) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';
$apellidos = (isset($_POST['apellidos'])) ? $_POST['apellidos'] : '';
$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$telefono = (isset($_POST['telefono'])) ? $_POST['telefono'] : '';
$opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

switch($opcion){
    case 1: //alta
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, apellidos, email, telefono) VALUES('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$email', '$telefono') ";            
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute(); 

        $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre, apellidos, email, telefono FROM clientes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
    case 2: //modificación
        $consulta = "UPDATE clientes SET nombre='$nombre', apellidos='$apellidos', email='$email', telefono='$telefono' WHERE id='$id' ";       
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();        
        
        $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre, apellidos, email, telefono FROM clientes WHERE id='$id' ";       
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;        
    case 3://baja
        $consulta = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id='$id' ";     
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();                           
        break;        
}

print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //enviar el array final en formato json a JS
$conexion = NULL;
?>
```

i've tryed to edit some parts and asked to chatgpt but i cant solve the problem

[proyect files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1BwJ.png)

Comment: It sounds like a request to crud.php is being made, but it's going to the wrong URL - presumably the file isn't in that location in your server. Looking at the internal code of crud.php isn't going to help you (or us) to fix that. Go look at your JS code which is generating that request.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use prepared statements **with parameters** to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / PDO. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using PDO. See also: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. You've got as far as using prepared statements, but if you don't also use parameters with them then your code is still vulnerable.

Comment: oh thanks for the answer, i dont really know where is the problem, i know its from the file location but i think i didn't set the wrong direcction, can i show you a pic of the proyect files?

Comment: No, pictures of code are not much use to anyone. Again, go and find the javascript code which built this url and made a request to it. That's where you need to make the correction. If you're not sure where it came from, the full stack trace of the error in the console should point you to it